# Searching strings in raw disk image

Tags: grep, search, disk-image, forensics

I am currently writing a tool that should scan a **readonly** raw disk image for a a given pattern.

The task is to get the byte offset of the match.

I am able to find simple text documents with
`grep -a -o -b -iE PATTERN IMAGE`, but i can not find a way to search through excel, pdfs and word documents.

I know that *grep* is not suitable for this task. Is there an other tool i can use?

Comment: I would say, forget it. Excel & Word files are zippped, so you would need to find the blocks they are contained in, so filesystem aware, concat then unzip the load in some way. Once you get to that stage, your code has to be xml aware and probably also has to recognise utf8 etc. PDF files are just as bad.

Comment: You're not looking for "_a tool that should scan a raw disk image for a given pattern_". You're looking for a filesystem-aware tool that also understands application file formats. At this point I'd split the problem into two parts - one that can extract files from a filesystem image, and one that can extract data from known application file formats

Comment: See http://www.sleuthkit.org/